# Using ExecuteInTransaction with UserManager

Tags: .net-core, ef-core-2.1, usermanager

We are implementing `EnableRetryOnFailure` but as discussed on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-resiliency, this does not work out of the box for user defined transactions.

One of the recommendations from the above link (options 3 & 4) is to use an `ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteInTransaction`, and to call `SaveChanges` with `acceptAllChangesOnSuccess: false`.

This is necessary so that the transaction can be retried if SaveChanges succeeds but the transaction fails.

The issue we are having is that we have `UserManager` methods wrapped up inside our transactions, and these will internally be calling `SaveChanges` on the context.

How can we do this, when we cannot change `UserManager` to use `acceptAllChangesOnSuccess: false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a user with the `UserManager.CreateAsync` method will call the `SaveChanges` method on the internal `UserStore`.
The `UserStore` class has a public property, `AutoSaveChanges`, that indicates whether to call the `SaveChanges` method.
By setting the `AutoSaveChanges` property to false and then calling the `UserManager.CreateAsync` method, the `SaveChanges` method will not be called.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/839cf8925278018903f53f22d580d15b0a59ca0f/src/Identity/EntityFrameworkCore/src/UserStore.cs#L141

1. set false to UserStore.AutoSaveChanges property.
2. userManager.CreateAsync(user) (no call SaveChanges)
3. context.SaveChanges(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess: false)

Comment: Please add few lines of explanation.